# Problem To Download playsound Module using pip

Tags: python, pip, module, mp3, playsound

### Playsound

`playsound` is a python module this module have only one function called playsound

**Why I am installing**: I want to play mp3 files

### Main Problem

I write this command (I use Mac)

```bash
pip3 install playsound
```

#### Error:

```bash
Collecting playsound
  Using cached playsound-1.3.0.tar.gz (7.7 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/5x/63vbr8wd1wn82svxg0tpck7h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-vg88gmen/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/5x/63vbr8wd1wn82svxg0tpck7h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-vg88gmen/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/5x/63vbr8wd1wn82svxg0tpck7h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-vg88gmen/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/private/var/folders/5x/63vbr8wd1wn82svxg0tpck7h0000gn/T/pip-build-env-vg88gmen/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/inspect.py", line 1282, in getsource
          lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/inspect.py", line 1264, in getsourcelines
          lines, lnum = findsource(object)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/inspect.py", line 1093, in findsource
          raise OSError('could not get source code')
      OSError: could not get source code
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

#### What I do to install

Comment: https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/issues/143

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue with python 12. Downgraded to python 3.10 solved the issue.
I found an issue on the topic.
A temporary solution is to use:

```
pip install playsound@git+https://github.com/taconi/playsound
```

Comment: Welcome. Please add supporting information to back your claim.